# Use MySQL to select the next one record after a matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, selection

How can I select all rows next to the row matching with the condition?

This is the table structure with 10 rows, but the number of rows increase in the future.

[Table structure](http://image.prntscr.com/image/730631bfab1f4d589d19e486b6e00867.png)
Plain text:

```
ID      Date        N1
1     DateTime    9  
2     DateTime    2
3     DateTime    5
4     DateTime    9
5     DateTime    3
6     DateTime    6
7     DateTime    7
8     DateTime    9
9     DateTime    3
10    DateTime    9
```

**Note:**
The "DateTime" string it's just symbolic, it would be any DateTime.

I am trying to know the first **N1** number after the number: **9**

I tried several ways but the result is not what I need.

The expected result is:

```
ID      Date        N1
2     DateTime      2
5     DateTime      3
9     DateTime      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Temp Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) to hold the `Id` of the records where `N1` is equal to `9`. You then select all the records from the `Times` table where the `Id` is what values are in the temp table *plus one* which is the very next record from the `Id` column the very next record after the `N1` value of `9`.

### SQL Query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE N1 = 9);
Select * FROM t1;

SELECT * FROM numbers
WHERE id IN (Select id+1 FROM t1);
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE id IN (SELECT ID+1 FROM numbers WHERE N1 = 9)
```

---

### Confirmation

> **Select * from Times**
>
> [image]
>
> **With above query**
>
> [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Temporary Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)
- [Create Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)
- [Drop Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html)

Comment: Not working for me, it shows IDs(1,4,8,10) Where the N1=9, read my latest comment in the question

Comment: I will try it again in my MySQL server, just to confirm a misstype from my part, but the first attempt did not work for me, give me a moment please

Comment: I know why it was not working, `Select * FROM t1;` it is present in your 3th line hahaha, works as expected, many thanks to you

Comment: But, if the `RowID` is not secuential? If I delete `ID 5` it can not show the `RowID 6`

Answer (score 1):

A better version of `Moderator Impersonator` answer would be:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE id IN (SELECT ID+1 FROM numbers WHERE N1 = 9)
```

Comment: I also updated my answer with this detail from this answer for you.

Comment: I posted the new question [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1198483/mysql-select-all-rows-after-matching-value-with-not-secuential-rowid)