# Use MySQL to select the next one record after a matching value without a sequential RowID

Tags: mysql, sql, selection

How can I select all rows next to the row matching with the condition? But considering there is not a secuential RowID like ID Field

This is the table structure with 10 rows, but the number of rows will increase in the future.

Plain text:

```
ID      Date        N1
1     DateTime    9  
2     DateTime    2
3     DateTime    5
4     DateTime    9
5     DateTime    3
6     DateTime    6
7     DateTime    7
8     DateTime    9
20    DateTime    3 //Sequence broken
21    DateTime    9
```

**Note:**
The "DateTime" string it's just symbolic, it would be any DateTime.

I am trying to know the first **N1** number after the number: **9**

I tried several ways but the result is not what I need.

The expected result is:

```
ID      Date        N1
2     DateTime      2
5     DateTime      3
20    DateTime      3
```

A simple way to achieve this was posted in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1198455/mysql-select-all-rows-after-matching-value) question, but only if the RowID keep the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two [Temporary Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) with one using the variable `@row_num` creating an index per row number and will increment each by one regardless of the `RowID` values. Then from this temp table you will select the `row_num+1` from it where the `N1` value equals `9`. From there you select the `id` and `N1` columns explicitly where `row_num` values match giving you the desired result.

### SQL Query

```
SET @row_num:=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS row_num, id, N1 FROM numbers);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (Select row_num+1 as row_num FROM t1 WHERE N1 = 9);

SELECT id, N1 FROM t1
WHERE row_num IN (Select * From t2);
```

---

### Confirmation

> **Select * From Numbers** *(`RowID` equaling `5` is missing here)*
>
> [image]
>
> **Above SQL Query**
>
> [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Temporary Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)
- [Create Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)
- [Drop Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html)
- [MySQL Row_Number Emulation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)